# baseAddresses in CreateServiceHost for WCF service

Tags: wcf

there is parameter called `Uri[] baseAddresses` when we create service host using `CreateServiceHost` method of `ServiceHostFactory` class.

when this method will be called ? what will be the value in baseaddresses array? from where it will be set ?

can we set it from our end ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you host your service on IIS or another container, it will be passed in automatically (from your config files and such).

If you host your service programmatically, it will be passed in by you. I am currently [having trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849319/wcf-hides-the-createservicehost-method-override-that-i-really-want) with the `CreateServiceHost` method itself, but if you use the standard `ServiceHost` class, here is how it would look (the array of `Uri` is what you are looking for):

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using MyApp.DatabaseService.Contracts; // IDatabase interface
using MyApp.DatabaseService.Impl; //DatabaseService

 public class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
                typeof(DatabaseService),
                new Uri[]{          // <-- baseAddresses
                    new Uri("http://localhost:8111/DatabaseService"),
                    new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/DatabaseService")
                }))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDatabase),
                    new BasicHttpBinding(),
                    "");

                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDatabase),
                    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                    "");

                // Add ability to browse through browser
                ServiceMetadataBehavior meta = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                meta.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(meta);

                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("IDatabase: DatabaseService");
                Console.WriteLine("Service Running. Press Enter to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();

                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```